# DolphinDB - Can't use Delta of Delta to compress POINT data

Tags: compression, dolphindb

Script:

```
pt = point(1 2 3 4, 1 2 3 4)
compress(pt,"delta")
```

Error Message:

```
compress(pt, "delta") => Delta compression only supports integral and temporal data
```

Answer (score 0):

Although an integer is inserted in when constructing the POINT type, the underlying storage is a POINT type, and the delta of delta compression does not support the compression of a floating point number.

[image]